# How to replace h2 tags by h3 in files only inside a specific div using notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to bulk replace h2 tags by h3 inside a specific div. Example :

```
        <div class="txt_contenu">
            <h2 style="text-align: justify;">blabla title</h2>
            <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor</strong> sit amet.</p>
            <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
            <h2 style="text-align: justify;">blabla title 2</h2>
            <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
            <p>other text example</p>
        </div>
```

Should become :

```
        <div class="txt_contenu">
            <h3 style="text-align: justify;">blabla title</h3>
            <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor</strong> sit amet.</p>
            <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
            <h3 style="text-align: justify;">blabla title 2</h3>
            <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
            <p>other text example</p>
        </div>
```

I'm not very good at regex, this is not my code, i'm using notepad++ to do the job but cannot find a working solution...

so if somebody has a solution easy to implement (i need to do this on a lot of html files), i would be ver very grateful.
Thx.

I have tried this regex :

```
(<div class=\"txt_contenu\">.*?)(h2)(.*?)(</div>)
```

and tried to replace in notepad++ with $1h3$3
it works but it target only the first h2 inside the div...

[screenshot of notepad++ find replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5QkH.jpg)

Comment: Is it possible to find other `<div>`s inside the `<div class="txt_contenu">`?

Comment: question edited explaining what was tried and what resulted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following regex/procedure:

1. Position the cursor at the beginning of the file (either by hand or with <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> or with <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> = 0)
2. Launch Replace dialog (<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
3. Check Search Mode = Regular Expression
4. **Uncheck** `Wrap around` (important, our you'll make notepad++ crash )
5. Find what => `((?:^|</div>)[\s\S]*?<div[ ]class="txt_contenu">)|\G((?:(?!</div>)[\s\S])*?)<h2([\s\S]*?)</h2>`
6. Replace by => `(?1\1)(?3\2<h3\3</h3>)`
7. <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

**NOTE**: This solution should work as long as there is no more divs inside the `<div class="txt_contenu">`

If you can find other divs inside the `<div class="txt_contenu">` (nested), then probably a solution with macros could be coded. Just let me know if that is the case.

---

**Test input**:

```
<h2>foobar</h2>
<div class="whatever">
    <h2>foobar</h2>
</div>
<div class="txt_contenu">
    <h2 style="text-align: justify;">blabla title</h2>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor</strong> sit amet.</p>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
    <h2 style="text-align: justify;">blabla title 2</h2>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p>other text example</p>
</div>
<h2>foobar</h2>
<div class="whatever">
    <h2>foobar</h2>
</div>
<div class="txt_contenu">
    <h2 style="text-align: justify;">blabla title</h2>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor</strong> sit amet.</p>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
    <h2 style="text-align: justify;">blabla title 2</h2>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p>other text example</p>
</div>
<h2>foobar</h2>
<div class="whatever">
    <h2>foobar</h2>
</div>
```

**Test output**:

```
<h2>foobar</h2>
<div class="whatever">
    <h2>foobar</h2>
</div>
<div class="txt_contenu">
    <h3 style="text-align: justify;">blabla title</h3>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor</strong> sit amet.</p>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
    <h3 style="text-align: justify;">blabla title 2</h3>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p>other text example</p>
</div>
<h2>foobar</h2>
<div class="whatever">
    <h2>foobar</h2>
</div>
<div class="txt_contenu">
    <h3 style="text-align: justify;">blabla title</h3>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor</strong> sit amet.</p>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
    <h3 style="text-align: justify;">blabla title 2</h3>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p>other text example</p>
</div>
<h2>foobar</h2>
<div class="whatever">
    <h2>foobar</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Julio,
This works exactly has you said. I have some files with a nested div inside and it works only for the first h2 and stops after the div...
But it's a quite acceptable solution and i think elaborating a macro for that job is time consuming.
I thank you very much has your solution is the best one and helped me a lot.
(even if i dont understand your regular expression...)